# How to add aframe a webcam background and shadows on this background?

Tags: background, webcam, aframe, shadow

In  I'd like to get user webcam as a simple background (== no tracking, markers...)
With the following code I got it, but there's no shadow on the webcam background.
I guess I should not use the aframe-ar.js, and I can see this example showing webcam mapped on a cube :
[webcam as aframe texture](https://glitch.com/%7Ewebcam-as-aframe-texture)

But how to get the webcam as a **simple background**? And then how to get shadows visible on this background?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.2/aframe.min.js"></script><!-- Master file for aframe (== a-scene) -->
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script><!-- display webcam -->    
    <script src="../js/play-all-model-animations.js"></script><!-- play animation -->
    <script src="../js/aframe-orbit-controls.min.js"></script><!-- orbit cam target -->
    <script src="../js/aframe-extras.js"></script><!-- pour cub-env-map -->
  </head>
  <body>
<a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" embedded>
     <a-assets>
     <a-asset-item id="toy" src="../assets/toyDrummerSolo-03.glb"></a-asset-item>
     </a-assets>
     <a-entity gltf-model="../assets/toyDrummerSolo-03.glb" play-all-model-animations="" shadow="" id="gltf">
     </a-entity>
     <a-entity camera look-controls  orbit-controls="target: 0 1 0; minDistance: 0.5; maxDistance: 60; initialPosition: 0 5 5"></a-entity>
     <a-entity id="keylight" light="type:point;intensity:2;castShadow:true;shadowCameraFar:100;shadowBias:-0.001;shadowMapHeight:2048;shadowMapWidth:2048;" position="2.40512 2.77634 2.73113"></a-entity>
     <a-entity id="ambient" light="type:hemisphere;color:#e5fdff;groundColor:#ffffff;intensity:0.5" visible=""></a-entity>
</a-scene>
<!-- no shadow on the webcam background -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There a couple of questions here, not sure which ones are resolved, so let me address the title:

**1. non a-frame background**

Without a `<a-sky>`, or background `<a-scene background="">` defined - any elements below the scene will be visible. [Like here:](https://jsfiddle.net/mq1wfecg/1/)

```
<img src="background-image">
<a-scene>
  <a-box></a-box>
</a-scene>
```

**1a. webcam background**

Almost the same as above, but instead as an img you need a video element:

```
<video></video>
// after the page is loaded:
// navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
//                       .then(stream => {
//                               video.srcObject = stream;
//                               video.play();
//                       })
```

Adjusting the sizes, for the scene to match the video can be tricky, but it's not the issue here.

**2. background shadows**

As the camera background has no physical surfaces to receive shadows - we'll have to imitate them. For example the shadows can be cast on an invisible `<a-plane>` element. Three.js has a special material for this: [ShadowMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/ShadowMaterial). A simplified example could look like this:

```
<video>
<a-scene>
  <a-box shadow>
  <a-plane rotation="-90 0 0" apply-shadowmaterial></a-plane>
</a-scene>
```

with a simple custom component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("apply-shadowmaterial", {
  init: function() {
    // grab the mesh
    let mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh");
    // keep the reference to the old material
    let tmp = mesh.material;
    // assign the new material
    mesh.material = new THREE.ShadowMaterial({ opacity: 0.6 });
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;
    // free memory
    tmp.dispose();
  }
});
```

Check it out [here](https://aframe-webcam-shadows.glitch.me/)(sloppy resizing, but i think this is not what matters here :))

Comment: Concerning the webcam background would it be possible to 'encapsulate' the video in <a-scene>, as I would like the video and a-scene start together when loading the page?

Comment: @ÉricLoillieux I'm not sure how ar.js does it, I don't think it encapsulates the `<video>` in `<a-scene>`. The video won't appear until the user allows using the camera anyway, so you could initialize the camera when the scene is ready, and add a loadnig screen until the stream isn't ready.

Comment: OK, many thanks for your help. I'm unable to write/read/understand any piece of javascript, perhaps I should learn...